# Use ReactiveCocoa 3 and 4 with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I'm new to ReactiveCocoa and would like to use it as a replacement for KVO on some `NSManagedObject`s in a Swift 2 project.

Most of the examples I found online use `RACObserve()`, which has been removed(?) in RAC 3. The [Changelog](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/v4.0-alpha.1/CHANGELOG.md) states, that the new versions de-emphesize KVO and I should move to `PropertyType`s.

Is there any way that I can use Reactive Cocoa 3 and 4 on an existing `NSManagedObject` in a similar way to what could be done with `RACObserve()`?

Comment: RACObserve is a macro, so you can't use it. But you can just use the underlying method rac_valuesForKeyPath in Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ReactiveCocoa 3.0 documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/FrameworkOverview.md#properties) points to the `DynamicProperty`

> The DynamicProperty type can be used to bridge to Objective-C APIs
>   that require Key-Value Coding (KVC) or Key-Value Observing (KVO), like
>   NSOperation. Note that most AppKit and UIKit properties do not support
>   KVO, so their changes should be observed through other mechanisms.
>   MutableProperty should be preferred over dynamic properties whenever
>   possible!

So you need to make an DynamicProperty object and use it's signalProducer. Something like this:

`DynamicProperty(object: managedObject, keyPath: "attribute").producer`

P. S. ReactiveCocoa source code has awesome [inline documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Property.swift). Checkout out it for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the usage example! I did find the recommendation of DynamicProperty, but misinterpreted how to use it. I thought it was a wrapper type like `MutableProperty`, but with KVC and KVO compliance and that using it would require me to change the interface of the NSManagedObject subclass.Your answer cleared up things a lot.